# How to pull words between starting word till '\n' new line. and is there any way to put 'OR' condition while extracting words in python?

Tags: python, regex

```
{mtd: LAct, cId: _M_, cTy: 300}
cId: ['2', '103', '201', '202', '1', '101']
cTy: 428
mtd: PAct
cId: ['104']
cTy: 428
mtd: CAct
cId: ['104']
cTy: 428
```

This is kind of text I have and would like to get *LAct, PAct, CAct* and *'2','101'* etc numbers from square brackets

I am trying something like this on regex evaluation portal (regex101.com)

```
(?<=cSId:).*?[\n]
```

But this doesn't work when I use same in python (re module)

```
re.findall('((?<=contentSourceId:).*?[\n]',myst)
```

Two questions:
1. How to get values LAct, PAct, CAct
2. And is there any way to put 'OR' condition to handle multiple 'cId', 'mtd' scenarios where I only want to get number and not **_M__**

Comment: Never use `.*?[\n]`, `.` does not match `\n`, thus, `.*` will suffice. And the answer is `re.findall(r'\b(?:cld|mtd):\s+(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)', text)`. Or, `r'\b(?:cld|mtd):\s+([^\W_]+)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks.. Sorry, I am a beginner at this but how to get numbers between square brackets. And why the solution provided by you is not working on regx evaluation portal like https://regex101.com/.

Comment: Probably you want `\b(?:cId|mtd):\s+(?:\[')?([^\W_]+)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/maBLuz/2/)

Comment: Nope, throwing an 'unexpected expression syntax error near '.  _re.findall('(?:cId|mtd):\s+(?:\[')?([^\W_]+)',mystr)]_ Also it's not working at the second line where multiple numbers are there (previously by mistakenly put cSId instead of 'cId')

Comment: `(?:cId):\s+(?:\[')\d+(?:\')` I am using this now. But ' is giving syntax error and `cId: ['2',` is getting selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?:cId|mtd):\s*(\[[^][]+]|[^\W_]+)
```

to extract the values you want, and then check if the captured text starts with `[`, and parse the result accordingly.

**NOTE**: This `re` + `ast` solution will only work if the values inside `[...]` are always known, comma-separated single-quote-wrapped numbers.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xt5CzH/1):

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:cId|mtd)` - `cId` or `mtd`
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\[[^][]+]|[^\W_]+)` - Group 1 (it is the value `re.findall` returns, the rest is treated as context):

  - `\[[^][]+]` - `[`, 1+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^\W_]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/24mPfN)

```
import re, ast
text = "{mtd: LAct, cId: _M_, cTy: 300}\n    cId: ['2', '103', '201', '202', '1', '101']\n    cTy: 428\n   mtd: PAct\n    cId: ['104']\n    cTy: 428\n    mtd: CAct\n    cId: ['104']\n    cTy: 428"

res = [];
for m in re.findall(r"\b(?:cId|mtd):\s*(\[[^][]+]|[^\W_]+)", text):
    if m.startswith("["):
        res.append(ast.literal_eval(m.replace("'", '')))
    else:
        res.append(m)

print(res)  # => ['LAct', [2, 103, 201, 202, 1, 101], 'PAct', [104], 'CAct', [104]]
```

If you need `['LAct', 2, 103, 201, 202, 1, 101, 'PAct', 104, 'CAct', 104]` as result use `res.extend(ast.literal_eval(m.replace("'", '')))`, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/07lPPt).

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding 'note' part

Comment: @AmRey Yes, if you want to make the regex more specific and only support those int single-quoted numbers in square brackets, use `\b(?:cId|mtd):\s*(\['\d+'(?:,\s*'\d+')*]|[^\W_]+)`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xt5CzH/2).

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew `{mtd: LAct, cId: _M_, cTy: 300} cId: ['2', '103', '201', '202', '1', '101'] cTy: 428 uCd: Wb/Utr_Gere_Rdo_VOwe vr: '0.0' mtd: PAct cId: ['104'] cTy: 428 mtd: CAct cId: ['104'] cTy: 428 uCd: Wb/Ui_Grt_Rod_VO vr: '0.0' ` with this I am trying to get all _uCd_ values using `\b(?:contentSourceId|method|useCaseId):\s*(\['\d+'(?:,\s*'\d+')*]|[^\W]+|[^a-zA-Z]+)` but only getting till _Wb_ each time.. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @AmRey You won't be able to use a single regex like this with `re`. The `uCd` values contain underscores. You will also extract `cId: _M_` then. Use another regex for that, `\buCd:\s*(\S+)`

Comment: Ok.. but all that stuff is part of one group.. may be I'll put them with two different functions..

Comment: @AmRey Or use PyPi regex module, you will be able to use a branch reset group within one regex

Comment: Ok.. great will explore that